# Injection MySQL - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-injection

I need some help with this. This is my code.
I have to do an injection test with this.
I've done my tests and gotten the fields from the database table as shown in the picture.
[image]

I have done this injection and put it in password field but it does not work.

`'; INSERT INTO gad_usuarios('usuario','contrasena') VALUES('123','123'); SELECT * FROM` gad_personal WHERE '1'='1`

Someone can help me to get into if true conditional.

```
$user    
name=$_POST["username"];
$passuser=$_POST["passuser"];
$sql= "
SELECT gad_usuarios.*,gad_personal.per_estado FROM gad_usuarios 
left join gad_personal on gad_usuarios.id_personal=gad_personal.id_personal
WHERE gad_usuarios.usuario = '$username' and gad_usuarios.contrasena='$passuser'  and gad_personal.per_estado='activo'";

$result=mysql_query($sql)or die("ERROR_".mysql_error());
if($count == 1)
{
 echo "OK";
}
else {
 echo "NO";
}
```

Comment: mysql_query can not execute 2 Statements. BTW. `mysql_*` API is deprecated. Do not use it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mysql_query` does not support multiple query execution, so you cannot inject an `INSERT` query with this code